# Python while loop condition check for string

Tags: python, while-loop

In Codeacademy, I ran this simple python program:

```
choice = raw_input('Enjoying the course? (y/n)')

while choice != 'y' or choice != 'Y' or choice != 'N' or choice != 'n':  # Fill in the condition (before the colon)
    choice = raw_input("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: ")
```

I entered y at the console but the loop never exited

So I did it in a different way

```
choice = raw_input('Enjoying the course? (y/n)')

while True:  # Fill in the condition (before the colon)
    if choice == 'y' or choice == 'Y' or choice == 'N' or choice == 'n':
        break
    choice = raw_input("Sorry, I didn't catch that. Enter again: ")
```

and this seems to work. No clue as to why

Comment: Hint: can you name a value of `choice` where `choice != 'y' or choice != 'Y'` evaluates to False? Additionally, [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) may be useful to you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have your logic inverted. Use `and` instead:

```
while choice != 'y' and choice != 'Y' and choice != 'N' and choice != 'n':
```

By using `or`, typing in `Y` means `choice != 'y'` is true, so the other `or` options no longer matter. `or` means *one* of the options must be true, and for any given value of `choice`, there is always at least one of your `!=` tests that is going to be true.

You could save yourself some typing work by using `choice.lower()` and test only against `y` and `n`, and then use membership testing:

```
while choice.lower() not in {'n', 'y'}:
```